# Using fiddler with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, fiddler

I am testing some proxy settings for our application but I need to test a proxy that requires Windows Authentication (or network credentials).

For testing, I assigned the credential of the proxy to the network credentials

```
System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
//proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("1", "1");
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

Currently, I use Fiddler with the `Require Proxy Authentication` rule turned on. How can I configure Fiddler so I can use the Windows credentials instead of the default "1" / "1" credentials?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Fiddler 4.6 I can turn on "Automatically Authenticate" under Composer -> Options. My WebAPI hosted in IIS using Windows Authentication is then successfully called. You can see three requests in the log for a single call.

1. `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
   Cache-Control: private
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
   WWW-Authenticate: NTLM`
2. `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYIBDTCCAQ...
   Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 09:38:22 GMT
   Content-Length: 341`
3. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   Expires: -1
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
   Persistent-Auth: true
   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oRsw...
   Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 09:38:22 GMT
   Content-Length: 4`

Comment: That seem promising. I'm not in the right environment to test this, but good find.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot easily do this with Fiddler; you'd need to calculate the credential challenge yourself and add the challenge in a response header after returning a HTTP/407 response with a Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate header.

In contrast, BASIC authentication is easily supported with a single response header, which is how Fiddler's "Require Proxy Authentication" feature works.

Answer (score 0):

WebMarshal is a web proxy that runs on windows. It can be configured to use Basic Authentication and NTLM Authentication. You can [download a free trial](https://www.trustwave.com/web-security/webmarshal/).