# SOAPUI says access denied but service works fine in IE

Tags: web-services, wcf, soapui

I'm using SoapUI 5.2.1 and accessing a IIS hosted web service on my domain. The web service has windows authentication enabled.

When I browse to the wsdl using internet explorer, it asks for my credentials, then shows the wsdl.

When I do the exact same with soapui, it prompts for my details, then fails and when I check the http log it sayus 'unauthorised: access is denied due to invalid credentials'.

But I'm entering it correctly, I've even tried various permutations of domain\username, username, leaving the domain text box blank or entering it there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914899/testing-web-service-with-soapui-and-windows-authentication

Comment: Did you set the permission Authenticate Preemptively under Preferences > Http Settings? ... And add authentication under Request > Auth or Project > Service Endpoints?

Comment: I ticked the box, and it still failed. I cannot find your other option anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to provide a lot more info than would fit into a comment...

The other setting that I was referring to is detailed here : https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html. If you are sure its windows credentials authentication, then use the NTLM setting. You may have to restart for the settings to take effect.

"Domain – add this for NTLM authentication challenges. If you are authenticating NTLM, make sure to note the following in your configurations:
File > Preferences > HTTP Settings tab > uncheck Authenticate Preemptively preference
for NTLM v2 provide your username as "DOMAIN\USERNAME" or at least as "\USERNAME""

If you still have issues, you can use BURP suite or Fiddler or similar proxy tools for proxy setup. BURP is an extensive security testing tool and may even be an overkill. Fiddler is a proxy. Check out these two links:

Burp : [Testing web service with SoapUI and Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914899/testing-web-service-with-soapui-and-windows-authentication)

Fiddler: [Using fiddler with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670332/using-fiddler-with-windows-authentication)