# asp.net core 2.0 web api and windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Creating simple asp.net core 2.0 web api application (RESTful services only) that uses windows authentication.  In my controller I defined a simple test method which just returns the username (json format).  When I used a restful client such as fiddler and invoke this method, e.g. http://localhost/webapi/testservice, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.  However when I put that url in a Web browser, it invokes successfully and returns the user back.

My question is, why does invoking the service work on the browser but not in a REST client like Fiddler?  Is there an additional header I need to add in the client when invoking the service?

Comment: It would help if you provide us with an [mcve]; without it we not help with much certainty.

Comment: this might help u -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430045/how-to-pass-windows-authentication-credential-from-client-to-web-api-service

Comment: @MithunPattankar I saw that link already but is not useful on my end since their solution of impersonation doesn't work in .NET Core

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670332/using-fiddler-with-windows-authentication